# Correct way to transform Object from Firebase list?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs

What is the correct way to transform a object from a firebase list observable?

The following code has some side effects and create duplicated results in my templates. The first time it loads correctly but after visiting the page a second time, duplicated results are showing up.

```
loadAccountUsers() {
        return this.af.database.list(`accounts/${this.authService.accountUID}/accountUsers`)
            .flatMap(list => list)
            .map((data: any) => {
                let role: string = (data.accountLevel === 10 ? 'Administrator' : 'User');
                return {
                    firstName: data.firstName,
                    lastName: data.lastName,
                    emailAddress: data.emailAddress,
                    role: role
                };
            })
            .scan((arr, val) => arr.concat([val]), [])
    }
```

When I don't transform the objects everything is fine

```
   loadAccountUsers() {
      return this.af.database.list(`accounts/${this.authService.accountUID}/accountUsers`)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`flatMap` emits each element of the list into the observable stream. When the database changes and another list is emitted, its elements are emitted, too. However, the `scan` operation is combining the emitted elements into a single array - hence the duplicates.

You could instead use the RxJS `map` operator and the `Array.prototype.map` method to solve the problem:

```
loadAccountUsers() {
    return this.af.database.list(`accounts/${this.authService.accountUID}/accountUsers`)
        .map((list) => list.map((data) => {
            let role: string = (data.accountLevel === 10 ? 'Administrator' : 'User');
            return {
                firstName: data.firstName,
                lastName: data.lastName,
                emailAddress: data.emailAddress,
                role: role
            };
        }));
}
```